how to use describeSecret on firebase cloud function
I am upgrading my cloud functions on firebase from the first generation to the secondI use defineSecret to get a secret I have created on Google cloud, I need to deploy the functions, but the process doe not complete and givees me this error:

Error: Cannot access the value of secret "private_key" during function deployment. Secret values are only available at runtime.

this is the code of my function:
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import {defineSecret, defineString} from "firebase-functions/params";
const clientEmail = defineString("client-email");
const privateKey= defineSecret("private_key");
const projectId = defineString("project_key");
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert({
        privateKey: privateKey.value().replace(/\\n/g, "\n"),
        projectId: projectId.value(),
        clientEmail: clientEmail.value(),
    }),
    databaseURL: "myUrl",
});

const db = admin.firestore();
const realtime = admin.database();
export {admin, db, realtime};

what the error says is obvious, but I do  not know what is wrong with my code; thanks in advance

The way your code is structured, you are calling admin.initializeApp at the global scope.  This means that the code is going to run during deployment, since the deployment process runs evaluates all code at the global scope including privateKey.value()).
The easiest thing to do is move all the calls to value() on a secret key to the inside of your Cloud Function call (not at the global scope).  Cloud Function implementations are not executed at deploy time (only run time).  That will remove the error message since you will be satisfying its stated requirement.
